How to handle Supabase Postgrest Exception in ASP.NET Core (controller-based web API)?
How do I handle Supabase Postgrest Exception in ASP.NET Core (controller-based  web API)?
I'm testing an endpoint (using Swagger) that gets a table row using non-existant (uuid) id.
This is the first line of response body I get (Internal Server Error):
Supabase.Postgrest.Exceptions.PostgrestException: {"code":"22P02","details":null,"hint":null,"message":"invalid input syntax for type uuid: \"non-existant-uuid\""}
Program.cs:
using Project.Services;
using Supabase;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

var url = "url" ?? "Unknown URL";
var key = "key";

var options = new SupabaseOptions
{
    AutoRefreshToken = true,
    AutoConnectRealtime = true,
};

builder.Services.AddSingleton(provider => new Supabase.Client(url, key, options));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DatabasesService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Model file (Databases.cs):
using Supabase.Postgrest.Models;
using Supabase.Postgrest.Attributes;

namespace Project.Models;

[Table("databases")]
public class Database : BaseModel
{
    [PrimaryKey("id", false)] // uuid
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")] // varchar
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

Service file (DatabasesService.cs):
using Project.Models;
using Supabase;

namespace Project.Services;

public class DatabasesService
{
    private readonly Client _supabaseClient;

    public DatabasesService(Client supabaseClient)
    {
        _supabaseClient = supabaseClient;
    }

    public async Task<List<Database>> GetAll()
    {
        var result = await _supabaseClient
            .From<Database>().Get();
        return result.Models;
    }

    public async Task<List<Database>> GetById(string id)
    {
        var result = await _supabaseClient
            .From<Database>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Get();
        return result.Models;
    }
}


Controller file (DatabasesController.cs):
using Project.Services;
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Project.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DatabasesController : ControllerBase
{
    DatabasesService _databasesService;

    public DatabasesController(DatabasesService databasesService) =>
        _databasesService = databasesService;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<Database>> GetAll() =>
        await _databasesService.GetAll();

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Database>> GetById(string id)
    {
        var response = await _databasesService.GetById(id);

        var database = response.FirstOrDefault();

        if (database is not null)
            return database;
        else
            return NotFound();
    }
}



You can check whether the data passed to the GetById method conforms to the type specification

I mananged to handle the exception by adding try - catch block (catching PostgrestException) in controller file.
